# Insert caption text to body

Tags: cross-referencing

The `\ref` command can refer only the number of the table, like the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
According to Table \ref{table} [[HERE]], we blah blah.
\begin{table}[tb]
  \caption{The caption of the table}
  \label{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline foo & bar \\ \hline\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like to insert the caption text into body after `\ref` (the position [[HERE]]).

like

> According to Table 1: "The caption of the table", we blah blah.

Not

> According to Table 1, we blah blah.

Are there any ways to insert caption text into body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, packages `nameref` or `titleref` provides to reference the title of captions (and sections, ...):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% nicer table lines
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{csquotes}% quotes with multilingual support
\usepackage{caption}% fixes the spacing around caption for tables
\begin{document}
According to Table \ref{table} \enquote{\nameref{table}}, we blah blah.
\begin{table}[tb]
  \centering % avoids additional vertical space of environment center
  \caption{The caption of the table}
  \label{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    foo & bar \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With package `titleref`:

```
\usepackage{titleref}
...\titleref{...}...
```

See also the comments for additional hints.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer works in my environment, too.

Comment: LyX users only: Simply select the "Textual reference" format in the Cross-reference dialog (this use `nameref`   in the background, do not mess with the LaTeX preamble for this).

Comment: And I found that you are one of the main­tainers of `nameref`! Thank you again for making useful pakcage! (and one of my friends also appreciates that.)